# Firewall for controlling network traffic

Tags: windows-7, windows, networking, firewall

I'm wondering if it is possible to have a firewall on Windows 7 that can only allow network traffic to one IP address, and from that one IP address?

I'm using a VPN that tunnels all my internet traffic to one I. However sometimes my computer will still receive traffic from other IP's, and send out to other IP addresses.

This happens especially if a program is already open before the VPN tunnel is established. If anyone would happen to know any decent freeware firewall that can do this, please let me know. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can use Windows 7 Firewall to do this, go to:

`Control Panel` -> `System and Security` -> `Windows Firewall`

On the left click on Advanced Settings this will open the Windows Firewall console.
On the left hand right-click on `Inbound Rules` and then select `New Rule`... 
If you follow the wizard you can define the scope, where you can allow a single IP that can connect to your PC